# Is it possible to change a flow of ZMQ messages with routing to a physical address?

Tags: networking, asynchronous, routes, zeromq, server

I might be misunderstanding this, but it seems like when using a `ROUTER/DEALER` pattern in `zmq` when the request is recieved by the responder it will have to travel back up the way it came.

It seems like it would incur less network latency to have the replier respond directly to the remote requester.

Is there any way to do this, maybe by passing the physical address instead of the `id`?

**Is it possible to create this sort of system?**

I would like to see a transmission chain something like this **`REQ`**->**`ROUTER`**->**`DEALER`**->**`REP`**->**`REQ`**, where both occurences of `REQ` represent the same machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do what you're looking for here, at least sort of... but don't abuse the system too much to make it operate in ways it's not intended to, or you'll create a maintenance nightmare for yourself.  Where the line sits for *"too far"* in this instance will be different per dev team and project, but keep that in mind.

Here's a few reasons why your proposed pattern will experience problems:

- Your DEALER socket is peered with to two other sockets.  DEALER sockets *send* data in round-robin fashion, so it'll send one message to your REP socket, and the next will go back to your ROUTER socket.  Probably not what you want.
- There's no clear server sockets (that you will `bind()` on) or client sockets (that you will `connect()` on).  In your proposed pattern, it works out because there's an even total of sockets, but if you were to add or remove a socket in the chain, you'd run into the following scenario:

-

```
SOCKET A  ->  SOCKET B  ->  SOCKET C  ->  (SOCKET A)
CLIENT        SERVER        CLIENT        ( CLIENT )
CONNECT       BIND          CONNECT       ( CONNECT)
```

A socket that `connect()`s can't connect to another socket that `connect()`s.  Same with two sockets that `bind()`.

- You're attempting to break the notion that a REQ socket expects a reply from the socket it sends the request to, and a REP socket replies to the socket that sent it the request.  If that's even possible (I haven't looked into it), that would be *my* line for "too far" and "expect maintenance headaches".

---

... Here's my advice:

- If you have not or are not, then [read the guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all).
- Messaging protocols are *hard*.  It seems like they should be easy, but they are easy to do wrong.  This is why it's probably a good idea to use an off-the-shelf protocol *even if* it seems less efficient to you.
- Don't prematurely optimize.  Odds are, the extra network latency is not going to be your bottleneck. How much data are you really passing around? Is there a way you could offload a majority of the data? e.g. if you're sending MB of data per message, could you store it in a centrally accessible repository and just send the URI in your message?
- There are lots of messaging protocols laid out in the guide and given away for free on the ZMQ resource site.  They are tested and well designed.  Unless they flat don't work for you, try and use them.

If you want to make your proposed messaging pattern work, you'll need to add sockets to it.  Each process should own an incoming and an outgoing socket (this will ensure there are always an even number of sockets and `bind()`ing and `connect()`ing should be managable.  You'll be able to maintain appropriate messaging for each socket type (not breaking REQ and REP expectations) by adding another socket that picks up the other half of the communication. But really and truly, you should look at the existing protocols and determine that they won't work for you and why first.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, it is, but there are few caveats in an otherwise logical question

ZeroMQ has no problem to pass any node's physical address encapsulated inside a message-payload, however there are reasons, why this is not solving your wish so straightforward as it might have looked for a first sight.

1. ZeroMQ is a powerful framework of smart, scaleable, formal patterns, atop of which user builds her/his own messaging systems. Thus using the formal patterns (alike `PUB/SUB` or `REQ/REP` ) means that you fully re-use their hard-wired properties ( their behaviour ), not just half or one third of that. Understanding the **behaviour** will enable you to build 
   higher-layers of functionalities you plan to develop, but no one can ( shall ) compromise the behavioural models of the ZeroMQ library primitives == the building blocks. It would have adverse effect to destabilise your building blocks, so rather integrate any new smarter  add-on features "**on top**" of a fully-functional primitive-relations, than trying to hack/smuggle things at the cost of losing the framework strengths and robustness.
2. ZeroMQ primitive may get connected to its counter-party via **several "transport-classes" at the same time** and this fact is absolutely transparent to the application logic. This means, that if your idea started in an `inproc:` "connected" `REQ`, your address-passing / routing will not work on the far end, where the `REP` node has no such transport-class compatible path to the originator and the address would either collide just by fortune, or be useless once it does not exist on the remote side, so the expected benefit of a faster/simpler routing of the answer back to the requestor ( skipping for this very moment the troubles on missing "handshaking" between the pair-wise cooperating peers once routing would skip/bypass the intermediating nodes' trajectory-segments and thus leave them awaiting a response, that would never come ... )

### Where to go for more details?

A best next step you may do for this is, in my opinion, to get a bit more global view, which may sound complicated for the first few things one tries to code with ZeroMQ, but if you at least jump to **page 265** of the [Code Connected, Volume 1](http://hintjens.wdfiles.com/local--files/main%3Afiles/cc1pe.pdf), if it were not the case of reading step-by-step there.

The fastest-ever learning-curve would be to have first an un-exposed view on the **Fig.60** *Republishing Updates* and **Fig.62** *HA Clone Server pair* for a possible High-availability approach and then go back to the roots, elements and details.

[image]